texture paint is not working
I created a model of shawarma, managed to make vegetables, meat and apply textures to them and correct them in texture paint, but when I applied the texture to the pita bread, only the normal is displayed in texture paint, I can draw on the model, but the result is visible only in the image, and now texture paint doesn't work on other elements, I tried changing images, but it didn't help. I'm using blender 4.2.2

Hello could you please share your file?

Make sure your viewport's shading mode is set to material preview.

In Solid View mode, your viewport will only display the active image node but as Lauloque suggests, Material Preview mode will show the full combination of the image textures. The top right of the header has the options for the viewport there.

@CraigDJones it helped, thanks
